# can't build linkparser on snow leopard

Tags: ruby, macos, link-grammar

I'm trying to build [LinkParser](http://deveiate.org/projects/Linguistics/wiki/LinkParser) in Ruby.

I have RVM Ruby 1.9.2, initially the installer failed to build LinkParser because [link-grammar](http://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/) wasn't present, but once I installed it with `sudo port install link-grammar`, the build error changed to this:

```
checking for pkg-config... yes
MacOS X build: fixing architecture flags:
  using the value in ARCHFLAGS environment variable ("-arch x86_64").
checking for dictionary_create() in -llink-grammar... yes
checking for link-grammar/link-includes.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

It says the `link-includes.h` file is missing. Are there any other packages I'm missing that need to be present in order to get this installed?

Answer (score 0):

the macports version is too old, It requires at least version 4.7.0 of link-grammar, so I just compiled it from source and it worked.